# Orbeon : Liferay Form Runner Proxy Portlet Preferences not saved

Tags: liferay, portlet, orbeon

I'm trying to implement the Form Runner Proxy Portlet into my Liferay portal but I have a problem.

In Orbeon, I have an application named "CUS07" and two forms named "CUS07" and "Test" (and Orbeon default app and forms).

I set the init parameters in "portlet.xml" to display "CUS07/CUS07" form by default.

It's working well. But when I go to the "Preferences" page in the portlet configuration and I set "Form Runner app name" to "CUS07" and "Form Runner form name" to "CUS07" and click on "Save" button, nothing change. The form displayed is still "Test" and when I go back to "Preferences" page, the fields are still filled with init parameters set in "portlet.xml".

I tried with different datas in portlet.xml and "Preferences" page (with default Orbeon forms and app), but it does not change anything, I can not override init parameters with portlet preferences.

Nothing is logged in catalina.out.

Is it a known issue or what can I try to find the reason of this problem ?

Thank you :)

Environment :
- CentOS
- Tomcat 7
- Liferay 6.2 CE
- Orbeon 4.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer on Twitter : https://twitter.com/mikew_satx/status/428752758984806400

This line :

```
<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
```

was missing in liferay-portlet.xml.

This is specific to Liferay 6.2.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify steps from below link, it might help you.

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/How+to+Add+a+Configuration+Page+to+a+Portlet

on your configuration action class you should be getting the parameter value (from your config jsp) & store it in preferences. This should update the value in preferences.

Comment: The portlet is provided by Orbeon into a war, but I checked on GitHub the source (written in Scala) and the preferences are correctly stored.

Comment: I can not try it right now on my platform but somebody gave me a clue on Twitter : https://twitter.com/mikew_satx/status/428752758984806400 . I will update if it works.