# Liferay portlet preference settings change

Tags: portlet, liferay-6

I have a portlet defined like below.

I am trying to change the portlet preference in liferay by clicking options-> default preference, then it gives me option to select different file then i select a different file and click on set preference button, the page gets refreshed but when i click on options -> default preference i see the original one not the one i have chosen before.

So the problem is i am not able to change the default preference.(Note: i have logged in with admin user).

Does it have anything to do with 
preferences-company-wide,instanceable properties?
I am trying different combinations but nothing works.
what are configuration,default preference and preference options? because in some sample i have seen they use configuration option to change the preferences,  is there any documentation on these? i am having tough time in changing the preferences.

Note: i use liferay 6.2

```
<portlet>
    <description>Sample</description>
    <portlet-name>Sample</portlet-name>
    <display-name>Sample</display-name>
    <portlet-class>com.sample.SampleCode</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>jspView</name>
        <value>/jsp/CustomView.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <name>jspEdit</name>
        <value>/jsp/CustomEdit.jsp</value>
    </init-param>       
    <!-- <expiration-cache>-1</expiration-cache> -->
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        <portlet-mode>VIEW</portlet-mode>
        <portlet-mode>EDIT</portlet-mode>
        <portlet-mode>config</portlet-mode>
        <portlet-mode>edit_defaults</portlet-mode>
        <portlet-mode>editpage</portlet-mode>
    </supports>
    <portlet-info>
        <title>Sample Portlet</title>
    </portlet-info>
    <portlet-preferences>
        <preference>
            <name>portletPreference</name>
            <value>sites/test/test.page</value>
        </preference>
    </portlet-preferences>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing

```
<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
```

in liferay-portlet.xml. can you try ?

similar problem 
[Orbeon : Liferay Form Runner Proxy Portlet Preferences not saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435074/orbeon-liferay-form-runner-proxy-portlet-preferences-not-saved/21449524#comment32370584_21449524)

Comment: I added the above entry, but still not able to change the preference.

Comment: Can you verify your steps here ? http://www.liferaysolution.com/2012/05/add-configuration-page-in-plugin.html

Comment: Thank you Ankit, the problem is with the namespace. <input id="<portlet:namespace/>param1" type="hidden" ../>     and in my process action method we do like  request.getParameter(response.getNamespace() + "param1");  If i say request.getParameter("param1") then it works fine..but i am wondering whether it would be JSR 286 complaint code

Comment: if you use <aui:input name="preferences--param1--" type="hidden" value="xyz" /> then request.getParameter("param1") should work.